# Greenplum turn strings into table

Tags: json, greenplum

Everyone, how does GP turn the strings looking like a dictionary As below into the table with field names and values.
I mean how to made it in SQL
`{"useCoupon":true,"useLevel":false,"usePoints":false,"useActivity" :false}`

Comment: Look up `row_to_json()`.

Answer (score 0):

create table test(a json);

insert into test(a) values('{"useCoupon":true,"useLevel":false,"usePoints":false,"useActivity" :false}');
insert into test(a) values('{"useCoupon":false,"useLevel":false,"usePoints":true,"useActivity" :true}');

After loading data to a staging table using copy or gpfdist or any another utilities, select the required fields like below and load the data to final table.

gpadmin=# select a -> 'useCoupon' as useCoupon,a -> 'useLevel' as useLevel,a -> 'usePoints' as usePoints,a -> 'useActivity' as useActivity from test;
usecoupon | uselevel | usepoints | useactivity

-----------+----------+-----------+-------------

true      | false    | false     | false

false     | false    | true      | true
(2 rows)